# Android: when user select an list of item retrieves from database,the sum must be calculated. How to do this?

Tags: android

What I want is when user select an list of item retrieves from database,the sum must be calculated. How to do this? Here is the code:

```cs
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

   private GridView gridView;
   private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
   private ArrayList<ProductItem> products;
   private DatabaseHandler db = null;
   private String url = null;
   private boolean displayUnchecked = true;
   ArrayList<Double>total=new ArrayList<Double>(); 


gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) {
          ProductItem selectedItem = products.get(position);
          CheckBox selected = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.selected);
            if(selected.isChecked())
            {
                selected.setChecked(false);
                db.deleteProduct(selectedItem);
            }
            else
            {
                selected.setChecked(true);
                db.addProduct(selectedItem);

            }
            //Log.d("Debug", selectedItem.getName());
        }

    });
```

Comment: can you please be more specific.....If you want to update the sum then you can use a session variable of integer type and where ever you are adding product then do SessionVariable's name + = your product price so similarly when you are deleting a product do SessionVariable's name - = product price (please also check the conditon for current price means as per requirement)

Comment: a list of item is displayed.when the user selects two items for example.the sum must be calculated.i am using checkbox